# unable to addClass() to <tr>

Tags: javascript, dojo

`onClick` on a link, I need to `addClass()` to the `<tr>` which contains the link and make its border yellow. I tried to access the `<tr>` by `this.parent`, but it did not work.
I got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
```

How do I resolve this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmgT4/)

**EDIT:**

Dojo Code:

```
function(dom, on, domClass){
    on(dom.byId("link1"), "click", function(){
        disableLink("link1");
        disableLink("link2");
        disableLink("link3");
        domClass.add(this.parent.parent, "style1");  // not working!
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The property is `parentNode` not `parent`
2. Disabling the element appears to blank the parentNode property, so access it *before* you disable the link

Comment: I changed it to `.parentNode` and it changed the `border` of `<td>` to `yellow` instead of that of the `<tr>`. I also tried `.parentNode.parentNode`, but it didnt work. EDIT: +1 for `.parentNode` :)

Comment: You have a border on the `td` elements already, that is covering up the border on the tr.

Comment: I changed the CSS so that the `background-color` is changed onClick. However, it is still changing it for the `<td>`.